# Installing lxml on Python 3 on a Mac

Tags: python

I have a new Mac and I installed python 3 using `brew install python`.

```
[~]$ which python3                                                rbenv:system 
/usr/local/bin/python3

[~]$ python3 --version                                            rbenv:system 
Python 3.8.6
```

I ran the following command:
pip3 install -r requirements.txt which has lxml==4.5.2 in it.

It installed fine with no errors. If I run it again I get this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: lxml==4.5.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (4.5.2)
```

However whenever I try to import lxml, I get an error:

```
[~]$ python3                                                      rbenv:system 
Python 3.8.6 (default, Oct  8 2020, 14:06:32) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lxml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'
>>>
```

Any ideas how to resolve this, I am using ohmyZSH so do I need to add anything to my .zshrc?

Some info on pip3:

```
*[master][~/src/Arelle]$ which pip3                               rbenv:system 
/usr/local/bin/pip3
*[master][~/src/Arelle]$ pip3 --version                           rbenv:system 
pip 20.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Comment: You installed lxml for `python3.9`, but the command `python3`resolves to an installation of `python3.8`.

Comment: any idea how to resolve?

Comment: Personally, I am using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to be able to manage different Python versions on my own. Have a look in `/usr/local/bin` usually there should be `python3.9` or something ?

Comment: To install the requirements for 3.8 you could: `python3 -m pip install requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `python3` and `pip3` can be binaries that use different versions of Python. Furthermore, there are virtual environments, which give you a local `site-packages` (folder for installed packages).

The best way to use `pip COMMAND` is with `python3 -m pip COMMAND`. That way you always know what Python installation your `pip` is doing work for.

In your case, run

```
python3 -m pip install lxml
```

in order to get `lxml` where you want it.